# Что быстрее: Javascript обработка или дополнительный запрос в MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, производительность

Всем доброго!

Есть в БД таблица  -А- : | id | field0 | field1 | field2 | field3 |

Теперь мне нужно, чтобы информация из field1, field1 и field3 хранились в field0, при этом сами столбцы field1, field1 и field3 я удалю. Таблица -А- : | id | field0 |

Из html через Javascript я обращаюсь в БД, чтобы вытащить информацию о какой-нибудь строке (по id). Какой вариант будет эффективнее с точки зрения скорости:

1. Я создаю таблицу -В-: | id1 | field1 | field2 | field3 | , при этом идентификатор строки id1 прописывается в field0 таблицы -А-. Преимущества: не нужен обработчик, все данные передаются как есть. Недостаток: в два раза больше записей и дополнительная таблица - дополнительные запросы.
2. Я эти поля храню как массив в поле field0 таблицы -А-, в формате типа JSON: field1:значение, field2:значение, field3:значение. Однако для распаковки массива будет работать обработчик JS. Преимущества: Одна строка, одна таблица. Недостаток: время на распаковку.

Старался объяснить понятно, но если что не так, я дополнительно объясню)

Чуть не забыл:

- в БД около миллиона записей;
- запросы редкие, пакетами по 5-10 в секунду.

Comment: 2. Вы считаете, что производительность JavaScript так сильно просядет на парсинге JSON с тремя значениями?

Comment: Я пока не разбираюсь в вопросах скорости, так что не знаю))
На самом деле, значений будет около 10-ти. Это сильно меняет картину?

Comment: @im0not, пока еще не везде стоят ssd (да и ssd не всегда панацея), действует такое правило: все простые операции чтения с диска заведомо медленнее простых вычислений на основе имеющихся переменных. Это если говорить про отвязанную от конкретной ситуации теорию.  
Про конкретную ситуацию: я сильно сомневаюсь, что вам действительно надо хранить эти данные упакованными. Если какая-то внешняя программа их требует в таком виде, то лучше дублировать данные или вообще создать view.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, други!)

Comment: @im0not если у тебя 3 значения , то проще хранить в формате (к примеру) значение1®значение2®значение3, где ® - любой символ не встречающийся в значениях1-3(если это строки, если цифры...), парсить будет проще  - split и вся недолга. и результат будет в массиве

Comment: @im0not твои подходы к работе с базой безграмотны. если у тебя есть -А- : | id | field0 | field1 | field2 | field3 |, то простым селектом ты можешь получить результат в виде field1:значение, field2:значение, field3:значение. и ничего не надо переделывать с таблицей . изучай mssql -concat, concat_ws. но лучше сформировать строку как в моём комментарии выше

Answer (score 1):

Соединять колонки в одну не надо.

В обоих случаях выполняется один SQL-запрос. Или запрос выбирает 10 колонок (id + 1, 2, 3, ... 10) или выбирает две колонки (id + {1, 2, 3, ..., 10}) - разницы в скорости, на малых размерах полей не будет. Если же типами данных является nvarchar(100), например, то разница будет несущественной, что две колонки прочитать, что двадцать две.

Выигрыш в скорости возможен, если используется тип text, blob - тип, который хранится не в самой таблице, а за её пределами, в системной таблице. Чтобы считать десять значений типа text, движок СУБД сделает десять чтений из системной таблицы. А чтобы считать одно значение типа text - одно чтение. Тут разница есть.